# displaying links if term is used

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I want to display a list of terms for navigation and am using:

```
<nav class="pagenav group">
            <ul>
            <?php 
            $terma = term_exists('group_a_teams', 'group' );
            if ($terma !== 0 && $terma !== null) { ?>

                <li>

                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( 'group_a_teams', 'group' ); ?>">Group A Teams</a></li>
            <?php } ?>

                            <?php 
            $termb = term_exists('group_b_teams', 'group' );

            if ($termb !== 0 && $termb !== null) { ?>
                <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( 'group_b_teams', 'group' ); ?>">Group B Teams</a></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

It works fine until I add in the if clauses so that if no taxonomy is applied it doesn't throw an error. The problem is that the terms do indeed exist but are not necessarily applied. Which function should I be using then?

Comment: I would use `!empty($terma)` instead of your conditional, but that code does seem to work when I test with known good values.

Comment: Apparently its not the conditional that was the problem but my slug `'group_b_teams'` etc. which became `'group_b_teams-2'` I suppose there is custom taxonmoy trash somewhere that needs to be emptied. Permalinks are refreshed so its not that. Thanks for your quick answer- as always ;)